# Get the name of a package in which a function is loaded in a way robust to roxygen

Tags: r, namespaces, package, roxygen2

I have two packages, let's call them `main_package` and `helper_package`. In `helper_package` I have a function like this:

```
helper_fn = function(r_package=environmentName(parent.frame())) {

    new_fn = function() {
       return(r_package)
    }

    return(new_fn)
}
```

In `main_package`, I call `helper_fn`:

```
#' @import helper_package
main_fn = helper_fn()
```

This works, and `main_fn` returns "main_package".  However, when I run roxygen to build documentation and NAMESPACE for `main_package` I get the following error.

```
Error: Failure in roxygen block beginning main_fn.R:1
using 'as.environment(NULL)' is defunct
Execution halted
```

roxygen is executing the code a different environment, it seems, `environmentName(parent.frame())` is `NULL`.  Is there a better way to do this that would allow roxygen to work?

Comment: What are you trying to document?

Comment: I want roxygen to build documentation, NAMESPACE, etc., for `main_package`.  It fails, and so `helper_package` isn't added as an import the NAMESPACE of `main_package`.

Comment: But why are you trying to document `main_fn` which is a string?

Comment: Ah, I see I've oversimplified this.  `main_fn` is a function created by `helper_fn` (I've edited the question).

Comment: The context is that helper_package is actually rnodejs, a generic interface to node.js modules.  You create a package that wraps a node module, import rnodejs, and create calls to that module with `helper_fn` (actually `node_fn`).

Comment: Can you please make a minimal reproducible example and file as a roxygen bug? This should work.

Comment: @Noam Occasionally I get this same error using RStudio.  I'm not sure why but closing RStudio and restarting seems to cure the issue.  I think it has to do with building a `helper` package while having the `main_package` open as a project in RStudio at the same time.  Not sure if you are using RStudio or if the underlying problem is the same but you could try it and see.

Comment: When I added a required package to the "Depends" field of my DESCRIPTION file the error was eliminated.